# Use UniGrid for a web part in Kentico?

Tags: kentico

I know there is a form control "UniGrid" in Kentico 8.2: https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/UniGrid

However, I cannot find it in the form controls for a property of my custom web part (in the web parts application). It simply isn't displayed there, no matter which data type I select for this property. However, I need its functionality.

Is there a way I can select it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unigrid is not a form control. [Kentico documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Developing+form+controls) says:

> Form controls provide the interface for the editing forms that allow users to input data in Kentico, both in the administration interface and on the live site. Each form control represents a single field, and displays a certain form element, such as a text box for user input, a group of radio buttons, an selector etc.

Unigrid is quite complex user control, which supports inline editing, sorting, ordering, filtering, transformations of the data displayed in columns, etc... and it is not very suitable to use it as a form control. 
Which specific functionality you need from UniGrid?

In your case I would try to use form control called **Uni Selector**.

[Here is an example](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Example+-+Custom+shipping+option+selection#Example-Customshippingoptionselection-Creatingacustomfieldinshippingoptions) how to use Uni Selector form control. This example demonstrates it on a new custom field in shipping option object, but you can use the same technique in Webparts.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I could use a possibilty to select and order (and perhaps filter) several pages. Thank you.